# Count the number of words & lines that has multiple vowels in python

Tags: python, string, optimization, split, substring

I am working on this coding problem "Count the number of words & lines that have more than X vowels for every Y words in every Z line"

Basically the input string has multiple lines and I need to count words that has X or more vowels in them. But the constraint is I need to consider only alternate Zth line as well as alternate Yth word in those Zth lines. For e.g. let's say I need to count every 3rd word that has 2 or more vowels in every 3rd line. So here `X=2`, `Y=3`, `Z=3`. Check below input string:

```
"1.When I first brought my cat home.
 2.It cost a lot to adopt her.
 3.I paid forty dollars for it.
 4.And then I had to buy litter, a litterbox.
 5.Also bought food, and dishes for her to eat out of. 
 6.There's a **leash** law for cats in Fort **Collins**.
 7.If they're not in your yard they have to be on a leash. 
 8.Anyway, my cat is my best friend. 
 9.I'm glad I got her. 
 10.She sleeps under the covers with me when it's cold."
```

Output: Word Count: 2, Line Count: 1

So based on criteria of `Z=3` i.e. count every 3rd line so the lines to be considered are `line number 3, 6, 9`. Also in these lines we need to count `Y=3 i.e. every 3rd word`. So words to be considered are `"forty, it" from line 3`, `"leash, cats, Collins" from line 6` and `"I" from line 9`. Given this criteria, the matching words with 2 or more vowels are found only in line 6 with words `"leash"` and `"Collins"` so the output is WordCount = 2 and LineCount = 1.

This is my first time writing anything in Python so wrote the basic below code:

```
class StringCount:  #Count the number of words & lines that have more than X vowels for every Y words in every Z line. 

    lines = list();
    totalMatchedLines = 0;
    totalMatchedWords = 0;
    matchedChars = 0;

    def __init__(self, inputString, vowelCount, skipWords, skipLines, wordDelimiter, lineDelimiter):
      self.inputString = inputString;
      self.vowelCount = vowelCount;
      self.skipWords = skipWords;
      self.skipLines = skipLines;
      self.wordDelimiter = wordDelimiter;

    def splitLines(self):
      if self.inputString.strip() == "":
        print ("Please enter a valid string!");
        return False;      
      self.lines = self.inputString.splitlines();

    def splitWords(self):      
      self.matchedWords = 0;
      self.matchedLines = 0;
      self.linesLength = len(self.lines);

      if self.linesLength < self.skipLines:
        print ("Input string should be greater than {0}" .format(self.skipLines));
        return False;

      lineCount = self.skipLines - 1;
      wordCount = self.skipWords - 1;
      lineInUse = "";
      words = list();

      while (lineCount < self.linesLength):
        self.matchedWords = 0;
        self.matchedLines = 0;
        self.words = self.lines[lineCount].split();
        self.wordsLength = len(self.words);
        wordCount = self.skipWords - 1;

        while (wordCount < self.wordsLength):
          self.matchedChars = 0;       
          for i in self.words[wordCount].lower():
            if(i=='a' or i=='e' or i=='i' or i=='o' or i=='u'):
              self.matchedChars += 1;              
          if self.matchedChars >= self.vowelCount:
            self.matchedWords += 1;
          wordCount += self.skipWords;

        if self.matchedWords > 0:
          self.matchedLines += 1;

        self.totalMatchedWords += self.matchedWords;
        self.totalMatchedLines += self.matchedLines;
        lineCount += self.skipLines;

      print ("WordCount = %s" % (self.totalMatchedWords));
      print ("LineCount = %s" % (self.totalMatchedLines));
```

Since this is my first Python code, I wanted to check how to optimize this code in both performance and line optimization. Are there any tricks to shorten the multiple while loops and a for loop?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If it works post it on codereview

Comment: The code works fine.

Comment: Post it on codereview, SO isn't for code optimization

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code works and the Asker just wants to optimise the code. It probably should go to codereview.SE

Comment: Thanks Ralf, I posted the code in codereview.

Answer (score 0):

This can be much more efficient with a translation table.  If you convert all the vowels in each word to the letter "a", you can use the count() method to count the vowels.  The rest is just a matter of traversing the list of lines and words which you can do with list comprehensions and range indexing:

```
vowels     = str.maketrans("aeiouAEIOU","aaaaaaaaaa")
X,Y,Z      = 2,3,3
counts     = [sum(word.translate(vowels).count("a")>=X for word in line.split(" ")[::Y]) for line in lines[Z-1::Z]]
lineCount  = sum(count>0 for count in counts)
wordCount  = sum(counts)

print(lineCount,wordCount) # 1 2
```